# All products are not showing on home page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I have to display all products on Home page in magento. I am using below code.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new_list.phtml"}}
```

This code is not working for me. I got error `There are no products matching the selection.`.

When I try to use root category id in this code then I can see only one product not all.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/new_list.phtml"}}
```

Somebody can help me How can I display all my products on my magento home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution of this issue. To display all products on home page, root category should be set as `Is Anchor = yes` in `display setting` in manage categories.

Answer (score 0):

Goto admin/manage category and in the root category 'Is Anchor" must be must be selected to "yes".